# IE problems with a website I am working on. Content area and sidebar overlap

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

If you go to this page:

http://aimeeandliamswedding.co.uk/home.php

in a browser such as chrome, firefox its good, it works fine,

however, visit the website in IE (the devil) and the main content area overlaps with the sidebar. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using strict mode instead of quirks?

Comment: quirks? i could try strict..see if that helps

Comment: yes thank you. i will accept now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no DOCTYPE. Your page is loading in quirks mode. Add this to the top of you page above the html element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few unconventional approaches in your CSS. Firstly why use absolute position?

You should add display: block; and float: left; to both your nav_menu and content containers. and they will align without overlap no matter the browser.

If you want to make it even more fault-proof, add display: table; to your wrapper, add another wrapper with display: table-row; around the menu and content, and then just make the menu and content display: table-cell.

Then you will have a div tag structure that acts as a table with 2 cells left and right, and it will never move a pixel.

Though remember, you should as a safe practice, provide width and height whenever possible, and remember float elements (if you decide to use display: block and float the elements which is a general practice in CSS) have sometimes the need of a CLEARFIX class (you can google it) but in your case i don't think it would be necessary if you provide width and height.